# Joint Moment Generating Function from Conditional and Marginal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation, moment-generating-functions

Suppose that that random variable $N$ follows a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda=6$.  Suppose that the conditional distribution of the random variable $X$, given that $N=n$, follows that of a $Binomial(n,0.6)$.

Find the Joint Moment Generating Function of $(N, X)$.

Initially I just tried to use the definition.  I found the joint PMF using the definition of the conditional distribution, but then I have to sum over both of them in order to find the joint MGF, and this was the step I was stuck at because trying to do a double sum over the product of the binomial and Poisson PMFs doesn't exactly go over very nicely.

Since this problem does NOT assume independence, I can't exactly attempt to use that to my advantage either... so now I'm stuck.  How can I calculate this joint MGF?

Comment: Start with the definition of joint mgf: $M_{N,X}(s,t) = E[e^{sN + tX}]$. Next you try to take a double expectation, conditional on $N$.

Answer (score 1):

The summations are doable. The joint pmf is
$$f_{X, N}(k, n) =
\operatorname P(X = k \mid N = n) \operatorname P(N = n) =
\binom n k p^k (1 - p)^{n - k} e^{-\lambda} \frac {\lambda^n} {n!}.$$
Sum over $k$ first:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n e^{s k + t n} f_{X, N}(k, n) =
e^{-\lambda} \frac {\lambda^n} {n!} e^{t n}
 \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom n k (p e^s)^k (1 - p)^{n - k} = \\
e^{-\lambda} \frac {\lambda^n} {n!} e^{t n} (p e^s + 1 - p)^n.$$
Then sum over $n$:
$$\operatorname E\left[ e^{s X + t N} \right] =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k = 0}^n e^{s k + t n} f_{X, N}(k, n) = \\
e^{-\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^\infty
 \frac {(\lambda e^t (p e^s + 1 - p))^n} {n!} = \\
\exp( -\lambda + \lambda e^t (p e^s + 1 - p)).$$

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly: $N\sim\mathcal{Poisson}(6)$ so $\mathsf M_N(u)=\mathrm e^{6(\mathrm e^u-1)}$.

  - You may find this by definition $\mathsf M_N(u)=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{uN})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \tfrac{(6\mathrm e^{u})^n\mathrm e^{-6}}{n!}$ and recall $\mathrm e^x:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x^n/n!)$
- Secondly: $X\mid N\sim\mathcal{Binomial}(N, 0.6)$ so $\mathsf M_{X\mid N}(v)=(0.4+0.6\mathrm e^v)^{N}$

  - Likewise $\mathsf M_{X\mid N}(v)=\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{N}{k}(0.6\mathrm e^v)^k(0.4)^{N-k}$, and recall the Binomial Expansion.
- Finally: put this together: $$\begin{align}\mathsf M_{N,X}(s,t)&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{sN+tX})&&\text{by definition}\\&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{sN}\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{tX}\mid N))&&\text{by tower rule}\\&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{sN}\mathsf M_{X\mid N}(t))&&\text{by definition}\\ &= \phantom{\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{sN}(1-0.6+0.6\mathrm e^t)^N)}&&\phantom{\text{as per above}}\\ &=\phantom{\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{(s+\ln(1-0.6+0.6\mathrm e^t))N})}&&\phantom{\text{by algebra}}\\&=\phantom{\mathsf M_N(s+\ln(1-0.6+0.6\mathrm e^t))}&&\phantom{\text{by definition}}\\&=\mathrm e^{6(\mathrm e^{s}(1-0.6+0.6\mathrm e^t)-1)}&&\phantom{\text{as per above}}\end{align}$$